# Effects of light wavelength on the Hamiltonian of the FMO complex

Tags: biophysics, biology, chemical-compounds, open-quantum-systems

Recently, I have been interested in the energy transfer within the [FMO complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenna-Matthews-Olson_complex). I was wondering, how could the wavelength of the light that excites the complex affect the energy transfer efficiency. In particular, could it affect the Coulomb couplings, or the site energies, both found in the Hamiltonian of the system?

I am using the Hamiltonian as described in the article [Environment-Assisted Quantum Transport](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0929).